# Ensure teardown runs in Test::Unit::TestCase?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, try-catch-finally, testunit

I'm using `Test::Unit::TestCase` to write some unit tests.  Currently, I have a `setup` function that moves and modifies some fixture files and folders on disk.  (This is a necessary evil at the moment.)  If a test crashes, the `teardown` method doesn't get called, leaving files and folders in the way.  The next time I run a test, it complains that such-and-such a folder already exists (`Errno::EEXIST`), making me have to stop and get rid of the left-over files.

How do I `ensure` that `teardown` is always run?  (`ensure` is the same idea as `finally` in some other languages.)

Comment: What do you mean "if a test crashes" ? The interpreter aborts ?

Comment: I meant that it errors out, say with an exception.

Comment: Could you post an example ? raising an exception or a syntax error is caught by the framework and the teardown method is called. Did you double check the method name is well spelled ?

Comment: Yeah, I thought it should too...  It does get called when there isn't an exception, so I thought I was just remembering wrong.  I'll try to post an example soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about making your `setup()` do some cleanup so that it works even if the file still exists ?

Comment: Yep, make a clearup routine and have teardown and setup both call it.

Comment: That's not a bad idea.  I'll try that out.

Comment: This seems to be working pretty well.  Making sure that `cleanup` doesn't get called twice erroneously is a little bit of a pain, but it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an on-exit hook in `setup`, then removing it in `teardown`:

```
class MyTestCase < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def clean_up!
    ...
  end

  def setup
    at_exit do
      unless @cleaned_up
        clean_up!
      end
    end
  end

  def teardown
    clean_up!
    @cleaned_up = true
  end

end
```